# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Dll not found Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

Below is the Error i am getting whenever `Playback.Initialization()` executes.

`Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or one of its dependencies`

The system cannot find the file specified.I have set the copy local as true in properties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the correct references in your project?

Most commonly used for Coded UI

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Extension
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Common
```